# How to fix base R when it loses the ability to find any characters in a script file?

Tags: r, find

Problem persists whether I use Ctrl+F or Edit...Find; whether searching Up or Down; and whether Match Case or Match Whole Word Only is selected or not.  Persists after multiple restarts of program.  I am running version 4.2.1.

Edit:  I'm using Rgui.exe, with Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have 4.2.1 installed, but it's working fine for me in 4.2.0.  Maybe try downgrading, or upgrade to the current 4.3.2?